# Can I use an ssh key for Azure git push deployment?

Tags: git, azure, azure-git-deployment

I've created a new Azure AD account and an Azure node web app. I can log in using `azure-cli` and I can git push deploy.

However instead of getting a password prompt every time I'd like to be able to authenticate using an ssh key. There's a Management Certificates section in the azure portal settings panel, and there's an `azure account cert export` option from the azure CLI, but I'm not sure either of those are what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to save your git password locally 
(on windows, when using msysgit:)

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

for other options, see [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)

Comment: Hint: After you ran this command, you still will be asked one more time for your password at the next `git push azure master`. But every next push will be without being asked for the password.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Web Apps does not support SSH so you need to use https. However you should only need to set the git remote once so confused why you would get prompted for a password each time. Here is an article that walks through the steps for enabling git push for Azure Web Apps, maybe there's a step you missed. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

hope that helps.

Comment: I do already have git push deployment working fine but with username/pw auth in git you do get prompted every time you push. Based on your linked article (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/#Step7) this seems to be the only auth method available. The github/bitbucket integration looks nice though.